# How to set the Quality option in Html5 video tag

Tags: angular, html, video

I am using HTML5 Video tag to show videos which works as expected.But i would like to add an video quality option similar like youtube.If anyone has tried it can you pls help me.I have tried with the [resolution switcher](https://kmoskwiak.github.io/videojs-resolution-switcher/) plugin but it does not show any quality link.

I am implementing this videotag option in Angular7

Comment: You could use [jwplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/)

Comment: I use plyr.io for that functionality